# Max and min of $f(x,y)$ on $\Omega$

Tags: real-analysis

$f(x,y)=\int_{x^2}^{y} te^{-t}log(1+t) dt$ on $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in R^2: 0\le x \le 1\ ;0 \le y\le x^2\}$;
g(t) is defined in $A=\{t \in R: t>-1\}$, g is $\in C^\infty(A)$ so g is R-integrable on $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed as usual; extrema for your smooth function will occur at critical points on the interior, or on the boundary. Finding the critical points (remembering the FTC and chain rule)
$$
\partial_xf(x,y)=-x^2e^{-x^2}\log(1+x^2)\cdot2x=0\implies x=0
$$
similarly
$$
\partial_yf(x,y)=ye^{-y}\log(1+y)=0\implies y=0
$$
yielding one candidate for an extremum of $(0,0)$, which happens to be on the boundary of the region $\Omega$.

Thus we may just check for extrema on $\partial \Omega$, we examine the single variate functions $f(x,0)$, $f(x,x^2)$ and $f(1,y)$ for $0\leq x,y\leq 1$ to check for extrema. Can you find the extrema of these single variable functions in the usual way and then compare all of them?

Comment: $f(x,x^2)=0$ ; $f(x,0)$ is decrescent and $f(1,y)$ is crescent.Is  there a min in (1,0)?

Comment: Is (0,0)  a Max?